# System Restore option in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, system-restore

I know that System Restore option is in Accessories in Windows XP, but it is at different place in Windows 7. Likewise, where can I find the System Restore point option in Windows 8?

Answer (score 2):

The article on *[Exploring Windows 8: How To Use System Restore In Windows 8](http://www.vikitech.com/11302/system-restore-windows-8)* gives all the information on how to do a system restore.

There are two ways to access it:

- either search "System Restore" in the Windows 8 Search bar
- or select "System and Security" in the control panel, then "Advanced System Settings", then the "System Protection" tab

From here, you can:

- turn on/off system protection
- allocate space to system protection
- create/delete restore points
- restore from a restore point